# ssis 2008 transactions

Tags: sql-server

I am using SSIS 2008 for the loading of data from txt file to sql. In this scenario I want to revert all the data if package failes in any component for that I used transaction: required at package level and transaction: supported at all data flow levels but it is not giving the desired results. Could any one give possible solutions to it.

Thanks
prav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Package**: 
`TransactionOption = Required`

**Containers**: 
`TransactionOption = Supported;  FailPackageOnFailure = True; ForceExecutionResult = None`

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be

A) IF Upload TextFile to SQL Package Success --> Do Step "X" ("X" is NEXT Step for example)

B) IF Upload TextFile to SQL Package FAILS --> Delete/Truncate Your Table Data --> Do Step "X" ("X" is NEXT Step for example)